# How to Find String Matches in a Dataframe Using Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to find close matches between a string of text and two columns of my data frame—'tickers' and/or 'company'.

This is a sample of the data frame:

```
cik     | tickers | company                      |
--------------------------------------------------
1090872 | A       |   Agilent Technologies Inc   |
--------------------------------------------------
4281    | AA      |   Alcoa Inc                  |
--------------------------------------------------
6201    | AAL     |   American Airlines Group Inc|
--------------------------------------------------
8177    | AAME    |   Atlantic American Corp     |
--------------------------------------------------
706688  | AAN     |   Aarons Inc                 |
--------------------------------------------------
320193  | AAPL    |   Apple Inc                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And this is how some text might look:

```
text = 'consectetur elementum Apple Inc Agilent Inc. Aenean porttitor porta magna AA American Airlines AAMC Aarons Inc AAPL e plumbs ernum. AA'
```

I would like to find all close matches in this text, and make the output something like:

```
The following companies were found in 'text':
- AAPL: Apple Inc
- A: Agilent Technologies Inc
- AA: American Airlines Group Inc
- AAN: Aarons Inc
```

Here's the code I have so far, but it's incomplete and I recognize it needs a different approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'cik': ['1090872', '4281', '6201', '8177', '706688', '320193'], 'ticker': ['A', 'AA', 'AAL', 'AAME', 'AAN', 'AAPL'], 'company': ['Agilent Technologies Inc', 'Alcoa Inc', 'American Airlines Group Inc', 'Atlantic American Corp', 'Aarons Inc', 'Apple Inc']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cik', 'ticker', 'company'])

text = 'consectetur elementum Apple Inc Agilent Inc. Aenean porttitor porta magna AA American Airlines AAMC Aarons Inc AAPL e plumbs ernum. AA'

ticker = df['ticker']
regex = re.compile(r"\b(?:" + "|".join(map(re.escape, ticker)) + r")\b")

matches = re.findall(regex, text)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Can you post your sample dataframe in a form that can be easily copied into someone else's code (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`)?  The sql database stuff seems irrelevant to the question, and it'll be easier to answer if people can just copy and paste your whole code block.

Comment: Good point and sorry about that. Just edited to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle this. First of all the set up based on your code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['1090872', 'A', 'Agilent Technologies Inc'], ['4281', 'AA', 'Alcoa Inc'],
       ['6201', 'AAL', 'American Airlines Group Inc'], ['8177', 'AAME', 'Atlantic American Corp'],
       ['706688', 'AAN', 'Aarons Inc'], ['320193', 'AAPL', 'Apple Inc']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cik', 'tickers', 'company'])
text = "consectetur elementum Apple Inc Agilent Inc. Aenean porttitor porta magna AA American \
Airlines AAMC Aarons Inc AAPL e plumbs ernum. AA"
df['text'] = text
df['found'] = None

company_values = df['company'].values
for val in company_values:
    row = df.loc[df['company'] == val]
    if row['text'].str.contains(val).any():
        df.loc[df['company'] == val, 'found'] = 'Yes'
# filter the results        
df.loc[df['found'] == 'Yes']
```

I think making text part of the dataframe and then searching which of the company's actually are found and then recording this in the `df['found']` column, which you can then filter to find the list of companies. Here I make an assumption that the dataframe contains only unique company names with their tickers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. If I just print the data frame at the end, it only found ```AAN``` and ```AAPL```; yet ```AAMC``` and ```AA``` are also in the text. Additionally, I want to look for close matches to the company name which this doesn't seem to do. For example, in the df it's ```American Airlines Group Inc``` and in the text it's ```American
Airlines```. I would still like that to be considered a match.

Comment: @MSD I see in that case regular expressions can be helpful. I will see if I can adapt the code to account for this.